# After new install of 20.04 firefox starting continues to have loading problems including freezing

Tags: firefox

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS. Firefox has since booting up caused freezes at different times. I have logged in remotely and ran `kill -9` to kill all instances of Firefox and the system recovers.  But now that I learned patience if I wait up to and beyond 5 minutes the system will run normally and Firefox will work as expected.  I have run `top` when remotely logged in but nothing shows as a problem and Firefox isn't even shown. I should say that most freezes happen as Firefox is loading.

There are no addons or plugins other than any that may have come installed from the start. Yet the problem persists through multiple reboots.

```
$ snap list

Name               Version             Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
bare               1.0                 5      latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core18             20211215            2284   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core20             20220114            1328   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-34-1804    0+git.3556cb3       77     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-3-38-2004    0+git.cd626d1       87     latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-59-g7bca6ae     1519   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snap-store         3.38.0-66-gbd5b8f7  558    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snapd              2.54.2              14549  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
```

```
$ dpkg -l firefox
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version                      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============================-============-======================================
ii  firefox        96.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64        Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla
```

```
$ uname -r
5.13.0-28-generic
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `snap list` and `dpkg -l firefox` and `free -h` and `uname -r`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to an 8400 GS video card. Start Firefox in safe mode, go to preferences and turn off all acceleration.